# From Wordpress form submit on-click event, how to call an external REST POST API?

Tags: forms

I am new to UI. I have created a REST API and a form in my Wordpress website. Could you please suggest how to make POST call to my REST endpoint on-click event of the form submit button?

1. How to open /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php in IDE? I am hosting the website in Godaddy.
2. How to get the value of each field of the form?
3. How to make POST call to my REST endpoint on-click event and get the POST API response?

Thank you for your help!
Nav

Comment: With the help of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

1. You donot need to edit or modify the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php as this is wp core file. If you want to use ajax you can [check here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)
2. For getting the values of form you can use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function of jQuery.
3. Please check the below code for calling REST API on click event.

   ```
    $('button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         dataType : "JSON",
         url : "/wp-json/v2/......",
         data : $(form#formID).serialize(),
         success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
         }
    });
   ```

   });

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div id="border">
  <form  action="/" id="registerSubmit">
    <div id="userError"></div>
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="10"/><br>
      <div id="emailError" ></div>
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="10" id="email"/><br>
      <div id="passError" ></div>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="10" id="password"/><br>
      <div id="passConfError" ></div>
      Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="passconf" size="10" id="passconf"/><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
  </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form_data = $("#registerSubmit").serialize() // returns all the data in your form
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
         data: {action: "save_form_data" , "data": form_data},
         success: function() {
              //success message mybe...
         }
     });
   });
```

PHP :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_form_data', 'my_ajax_save_form_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_form_data', 'my_ajax_save_form_data' );

function my_ajax_save_form_data() {
    $form_data = $_POST['data']; 
  /* here you can use CURL for post data to other your rest API */
}
```